# Material 2 - autocomplete not showing options

Tags: angular, angular-material2, md-autocomplete

I am trying to implement `md-autocomplete` of `material-2` in `angular`. The way its suppose to work is when the user starts typing it would make an `http` call to get the data and will display in options. 
I am able to make the http calls but for some reason it wont show it in `options`.

**Html** :

```
<md-input-container>
  <input mdInput placeholder="Search drug" [mdAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="drug" showPanel="false">
</md-input-container>

<md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">

  <md-option *ngFor="let drug of filteredDrugs | async" [value]="drug.drugname">
    {{ drug.drugname}}
  </md-option>
</md-autocomplete>
```

**TS** :

```
export class DialogAutoComplete {
  drug: FormControl;
  drugList = [];
  filteredDrugs: any;

  constructor(public dialogRef: MdDialogRef<DialogAutoComplete>, private getData: GetData) {
    this.drug = new FormControl();
    //this.filteredDrugs = 
    this.filteredDrugs = this.drug.valueChanges.startWith(null)
      .map(drugname => {

        return Array.of(this.getDrugs(drugname)) || [{}];
      });


  }
  getDrugs(val: string) {
    console.log("filterdrugs is called ", val);
    return val ?
      // this.drugList.filter(option => option)
      this.getData.getDataForAutoComplete(val).subscribe(
        (response: Response) => { console.log(response); return response || []; },
        (err) => console.log(err)

      )
      : [{ drugname: "No Such drug found" }];
  }
  displayFn(drug) {
    console.log("displayfn => ", drug);
    return drug == null ? drug : drug.drugname;
  }
}
```

Below is the response of the `http` call.

[image]

Demo **plunker** with a different api call but similar response and setup. [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ce3cTgNzqKbfQrrhPE6L?p=preview)

Appreciate the help.

Comment: A plunker would be really helpful to diagnose and solve the problem :)

Comment: `http` call is in local env.. it wont work in plunker as it would need `https`.

Comment: @BhavikPatel you can create a mock json file and raise the http call. Use this demo plunker from this [**post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42655795/parsing-json-into-a-angular-2-object)

Comment: ok thanks, let me try

Comment: added a plunker. thanks

Comment: I see a table and no code like the above in the plunker it says Last Updated 8 days ago

Comment: let me check tht

Comment: try now please. i have edited the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `filteredDrugs` an observable which gets its data from any service (HttpService) in the format you want .

https://blog.bouzekri.net/2016-05-15-angular2-rxjs-simple-paginated-list-with-search-field

Async as defined by you `*ngFor="let drug of filteredDrugs | async"` helps to take the value of `filterDrugs` during runtime and hence `filteredDrugs` needs to be an Observable.

Helpful link : [AutoComplete tutorial](https://medium.com/@nacimidjakirene/angular-search-autosuggest-with-observables-6f42987f80e6)

Comment: thank you for your input. I did try this but it did not work.

Comment: Same concept explained here : https://medium.com/@nacimidjakirene/angular-search-autosuggest-with-observables-6f42987f80e6

Comment: the link kind of helped me. Thank you.